# How to keep a copy of a Google Doc even after the owner deletes it?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

I noticed that when the owner permanently deletes a document, it becomes unavailable to users sharing it. How can I ensure that I keep a copy (with the latest changes) of it even if it's permanently deleted?

I can log in to both Google accounts; one of them (the owner one) is maintained by my company.

Comment: back it up on your Drive

Answer (score 1):

Once you make a copy of a document with an editor/viewer account, the copy will be kept on the Drive unit of the copier even if the original file is deleted.

Comment: Do you mean locally on the machine?

Comment: @mshwf In the context of the question you could make the copy on Google Drive or locally.

Comment: @mshwf in the Google Drive web app, you can right-click and select "Make a copy".